# mp4 file streaming with php via nginx's "X-Accel-Redirect" not working on android

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, webserver, mp4

The problem is quite simple. I'm trying to stream a file with php via via nginx's "X-Accel-Redirect" header, because it's less expensive to let nginx handle everything than streaming with php.

I'm using Chrome on both pc and Android to test.

Suppose that I have a file in the public root directory: `example.com/video.mp4` This works just fine, both on pc and Android.

However, if I try to stream a file with the header "X-Accel-Redirect" (suppose that it's private, and it cannot be in the public directory), using this code:

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /path/to/protected/directory/video.mp4');
```

It works on pc, but not on Android. The requests headers seems identical, and I honestly don't know what to search.

I've also checked the headers on both devices, they seem to be identical.

Comment: yeah but are the response headers identical? eg, there's no special headers for "the mobile version of the site" or something like that?

Comment: maybe there's some stupid user-agent specific code running? or maybe the mobile browser don't understand the response headers, whilst the desktop browser does?

Comment: There is no special headers for mobile or agent detection. nginx doesn't check the user agent. Note: the video shows on Android, but is empty and cannot be played. I've already connected the Chrome application on Android to pc, and the console doesn't show any error.

Comment: Obviously the problem is with Android not liking what your server is doing. Make sure (via Google) that "X-Accel-Redirect" means something to Android browser. For example they may disable re-directs on mobile as a security measure against dodgy websites re-directing to data-draining content that wasn't asked for. Also does `/path/to/...` look something like `https://www.example.com/protected/dir/video.mp4`? Make sure your redirect path is of **https** type since that can solve some access issues.

Comment: @VC.One "X-Accel-Redirect" is internal to nginx, there is no redirect externally. nginx takes care of serving the file.

Comment: Have you ever found the solution to this? Having the same problem but with .mp3 files.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't.